# How would I enable the logging of statistics to the Excel spreadsheet in Arena?

Tags: arena-simulation

I have a simple question that I cannot seem to find a solution for.

I am working through the examples in the tutorials in Arena 16.2. No matter what I do or record in the simulation, the Excel spreadsheet that appears at the end of the replicate runs is always empty.

I noticed that the Excel spreadsheet output is always empty for the Example simulations and SMARTS as well. These are simulations used to walk users through the output statistics.

**Question**

How do you enable the statistics on entities, resources, variables, etc. to the spreadsheet? Does this require the instrumentation of the simulation with record blocks?

**What I have tried**

- Added record blocks for entity statistics. I had to attach the old template for Basic blocks to add record blocks. This has no effect.
- In Project Parameters, all options are checked for Statistics Collection under Run Control.